Unity 2D: how to intelligently navigate around other moving objects and obstacles when encountered
In Unity 2D, I have made an object move along a path by drawing a path constructed as a List data structure. Now I need the object to intelligently navigate around other moving objects and obstacles when encountered. What should I do?
(Since my mechanism involves more than just start and end points, I cannot use automatic pathfinding and obstacle avoidance mechanisms.)
This is a screenshot of my game project:
enter image description here
A visual example to illustrate why I think NavMesh is not feasible:
In this image, the red path points are reachable, while the blue path points are inaccessible due to being inside other objects. If NavMesh is used, it would attempt to reach both blue and red path points as end points, whereas in reality, the blue path points are unattainable no matter how one tries to navigate around them.
enter image description here
Here is the code of movement:
        MoveAlongPathRoutine()
        {
            animationActive = true;
            int currentPointIndex = 0;
            Vector2 startPosition = transform.position;
            Vector2 endPosition = pathPoints[currentPointIndex];

            while (currentPointIndex < pathPoints.Count)
            {
                while (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, endPosition) > 0.1f)
                {

                    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

                    AvoidCollisions();

                    yield return null; 
                }

                currentPointIndex++;
                if (currentPointIndex < pathPoints.Count)
                {
                    endPosition = pathPoints[currentPointIndex];
                }
            }

            transform.position = endPosition;

            pathPoints.Clear();
            animationActive = false;
        }

I tried changing the object's movement direction to move perpendicular to the collision ray's direction in order to bypass the obstacle. However, the result was poor, as my game object kept circling around that object incessantly.

You should absolutely use NavMesh. It can cope with moving obstacles, and you can chain together path endpoints to get your desired behaviour. You could look into implementing your own A* with multiple points but that seems harder.

Yes, when the issue involves multiple pre-built moving points rather than just start and end points, it becomes quite challenging, and I haven't found a suitable solution yet.

Just have each point be the end point and move the end point to the next when one is reached. Otherwise you are going to have to impliment your own pathfinding wich will be significanly more challenging

Thank you for your response, but using each point on the path as a NavMesh endpoint is not feasible in my project because the points on my path may pass through the interiors of other obstacles. Moreover, my game objects and obstacles have non-overlapping areas, so it's not actually possible to move to those points inside the obstacles. Instead, I must modify these path points to detour around them, rather than attempting to reach these path points.

Could you please add a visual example to illustrate why you think NavMesh is not feasible.

Dear shingo, I have added the illustration and picture

You can create some NavMeshObstacles in the blue dot area, an NavMeshAgent will attempt to bypass the obstacles while moving.

"Doing a detour around objects that cannot be passed through" is exactly what a navmesh agent does :) You don't have to use them but consider reading up on them a bit more before dismissing them perhaps.

Thank you both for your suggestions, I will have it a try, very much appreciated.

Alternative for larger groups of objects with multiple rule sets could be Boids

The "ray" gives you a relative "destination point" (if you don't have an actual one) that you can use to avoid "going in circles". As you move perpendicular (and forward when you can), you're constantly testing if the destination point is now in reach ... at which point, you change direction and advance on the estimated destination point to get back on the line of direction.

The above explanation was for you to be able to implement something similar to navigation but in much smaller dimensions.
If you want to follow your own path, when you reach each point, you should check the next point to see if there is anything that could block your movement. If there is, define a new point instead of that point, but increase its position on the x position, for example, slightly more than the position of the point and check the new point again. If it was ok, go to that point and then check the next point. If it is not OK, add a value to the x position of the new point position and check the new position again.
Continue like this until you reach the penultimate point.
Of course, you have to make a condition that if the position of your new point after successive additions to the value of the x position is greater than a certain limit, set the position of the new point equal to the position of that point and this time subtract the value in the x position and check the points
It was an idea that came to my mind at the moment and I hope it will help you.
But if you want to use another method, you can also test this method.
You can write a script and divide the map into small squares and create a list of these squares with positions.
After the current position to the target point, select the squares close to the target and check whether it is possible to walk or not, if not, check the nearest square and if yes, go to the next square close to the current square and the target. Add the position of this square to the list of waypoints.
Continue like this until you reach the square closest to the goal.
Add all these squares that are valid to a list and finally you can form a list of points that will lead you to the target point with the least amount of confusion.
You can also use ray to check the valid square.
I apologize for my poor English.

You're welcome. I hope it has been somewhat helpful.
